# Getting source code of installed kernel version

Tags: 16.04, kernel, source-code

To get the source code of currently installed kernel version(4.4.0-59-generic), I'm running:

```
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

This command gives source code for the latest version instead(4.4.134).

1. How can I resolve this?
2. And is there any other way to get the source code? I was not able to find source code for this version(4.4.0-59-generic) on kernel archives (https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/).

Comment: You are making a mistake somewhere. `$(uname -r)` IS the current running kernel.  Please provide results of `echo $(uname -r)` in the question. And it also gives you the answer: why don't you type the kernel version you want instead of replacing it by `$uname -r`?

Comment: @Rinzwind Because that's the same thing, doesn't make a difference. It's not a syntax error, it's because of how the `apt-get source` command works.

Also, `echo $(uname -r) = 4.4.0-59-generic`

Comment: Struggling with the same issue currently. `uname -r` gives 5.15.0-73-generic, but the install command downloads sources for a different version. Apt says "Picking 'linux-signed-hwe-5.15' as source package instead of 'linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic'", which seems to link to a different version, namely 5.15.0-78

Did you manage to resolve this?